# Is there any way to Promisify Unilateral Messages such as Worker Messages or WebSocket Messages?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to Promisify Unilateral Messages such as Worker Messages or WebSocket Messages?

I would like to turn socket messages, and worker messages to Promises if possible.  Is there any way to do that?
such as:

myWebWorker.postMessage('someMessage').then()...

Perhaps by subscribing to a bus of some kind, or through the use of Observables?  It seems as Vue.js has something like this available using vue-worker. (https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-workers/)
How do they do it?  Is it only for inline WebWorkers?  I would like to work with an external file if I can for the WebWorker.  I would like to be able to do the same thing for socket messages from the server too.  For Example:

socket.sendMessage('someMessage').then()...

Any Ideas?

Comment: You just need to wrap the method in a Promise constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the promise constructor to resolve the onmessage callback.

```js
const sendMessage = (socket, message) => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  const handleRes = (e) => {
    resolve(e)
    socket.removeEventListener('message', handleRes) 
  }
  const handleRej = (e) => {
    reject(e)
    socket.removeEventListener('error', handleRej)
  }
  socket.addEventListener('message', handleRes)
  socket.addEventListener('error', handleRej)
  socket.send(message)
})
```

Comment: If I had multiple outgoing messages that are going out asynchronously, wouldn't the socket.onmessage be possibly overwritten on different messages being sent out?  And then wouldn't those messages be not handled correctly?

Comment: @JustinLevine then use socket.addEventListener

Comment: So you are suggesting to add an eventListener on each message, perhaps with a unique identifier as an event.  And then what?  Destroying the eventListener after it resolves?

Comment: @JustinLevine I edited the answer to only run the callback once.